# Strange error while submitting to AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

When I try to submit an update to AppStore, I receive this strange and new error, **ERROR ITMS-90357**

```
ERROR ITMS-90357: "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for NSExtensionMainStoryboard in the Info.plist of extension Times.app/PlugIns/Times Widget.appex is invalid. The file 'MainInterface.storyboardc' is not present or will not load in some locales."
```

Comment: set deployment target above 8.2

Comment: great, let me check!

Comment: Didn't work, now checking Podfiles for iOS > 8.2

Comment: It's not even about Podfiles, stuck :|

Comment: Seems the problem is solved by copying MainInterface to root folder of project and escape from Localization well!

Comment: #AVbrahimi seems cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by copying MainInterface to root folder of project and escape from Localization well!

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to clean the project (Xamarin) and it worked after that.